# Python Class function calls

Tags: python, class, function

I have the following code

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fileA = os.path.join(dir, file)
        self._stuffA = 'NONE'

    def log(self, message):
        # Checks if the log file exists and if not creates a new one. 
        # Attempts to open the log file. If it cannot it raises an error
        try:
            log_file = open(self._fileA, 'ab')
        except IOError, e:
            print "!!! ERROR !!! - " + str(e)
            return 0

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        # Sets up the date and the log file entry
        message = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' - ' + str(message)
        # Writes the log entry then places a newline and closes the log file.
        log_file.write(logmsg)
        log_file.write('\n')
        log_file.close()

    def cleanup(self):
        logmsg = '----- ENDED SEARCH -----'
        self.log(logmsg)
```

Now this is just a snippet I left out quite a bit. But when the log function is being called from within my class. It just writes the last message to the file vice the new one being sent to it from the cleanup function. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the ``logging`` module?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What is happening, and what did you expect to happen? How many calls to the log function are there which are required for the expected behavior? (I expect at least two.) Also: your log file is text, you should not open it as binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write `logmsg` to the file, but never define it in your function:

```
    log_file.write(logmsg)
```

You must have a `logmsg` global that is being used instead.

Your actual message variable is called `message`, write that instead:

```
    log_file.write(message)
```

Comment: LOL yep thanks. Stupid overlook.